# how to make the photo field optional in react native

Tags: react-native, api

in React native can anyone tell me how to make the responsePath optional thats how i make it optional using && but it is not working in case of photo field can anyone help me out below are the codes.first is of redux how i send the data using formdata and 2nd is of component where i called this api function of redux.

redux//

```
export const addMember = (formValues, actions, key, resourcePath) => {
 return async dispatch => {
 const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');

const formdata = new FormData();

formdata.append('name', formValues.name);
formdata.append('age', formValues.age);
formdata.append('relation', formValues.relation);
formdata.append('gender', key);
formValues.mobile && formdata.append('mobile', formValues.mobile);
formValues.blood_group &&
  formdata.append('blood_group', formValues.blood_group);
formValues.height && formdata.append('height', formValues.height);
formValues.weight && formdata.append('weight', formValues.weight);
formValues.email && formdata.append('email', formValues.email);

resourcePath && formdata.append('photo', resourcePath);

console.log(formdata, 'for mdata');
let response = await fetch(
  'https://theeasylab.com/admin/api/auth/add-family-member',
  {
    method: 'post',
    body: formdata,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
  },
)
  .then(res => {
    return res;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    actions.setErrors(error?.response?.data.error);
    return error.response;
  });



dispatch({
  type: 'ADD_MEMBER',
  payload: response,
});

};
```

};

component //

```
submitAddMemeber = (values, actions) => {
 
  this.props
    .addMember(
      values,
      actions,
      this.state.itemValue.key,
      
      this.state.resourcePath  
     )
     };
```

Comment: When you say it's not working, what do you mean, is there an error

Comment: yes giving error like TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.errors.name') this show only when the photo field is empty

Comment: Where in the code is props.errors.name?

Comment: its working now,....i have send the image in formik only